# MySQL query from PHP executes only first query only

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem in following code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
?>
<?php  #insert new tweets 
if($user_id){
if($_POST['post_id']!=""){
    include 'connect.php';
    mysqli_query($conn,"Delete from post where id=".$_POST['post_id']."");
    mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users
                 SET post = post - 1
                 WHERE username=$user_id");

    }
}
header("Location: .");
?>
```

The first query Delete works, but the second Update doesn't, what's wrong in my code?
It redirects to header fine.

Comment: ` WHERE username=$user_id"`  are you sure `username` field contain the id of the user?

Comment: are you getting any error? first run the query in database to check if query has any mistakes .

Comment: OMG, thats it!!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: What is the return value of `mysqli_query` in this case?  Updating zero records is a valid result if no records match the criteria.  Also, be aware that your code is highly vulnerable to SQL injection.  This is not only a security issue, but makes the code much more error prone.  And, well, you're not checking for errors...

Comment: username should be id, that solved it

Comment: Anyone with access to this webpage can destroy your entire mysql database within 10 seconds. This is HIGHLY insecure. Google "SQL Injections". Really, everything completely wiped within 10 seconds. Do not take this lightly.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). I would advise sanitizing your input first before transmitting it to that database.

I think you have a typo in your second query

```
UPDATE users SET post = post - 1 WHERE username=$user_id;
```

username should probably be user_id. Because the query can not find a matching record, it appears as if nothing is executed.

You can always verify this by checking the return value of [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Comment: It's not sanitizing, it's escaping or using prepared statements with placeholder values. Sanitizing only cleans the data, removes junk. It provides no guarantee of SQL safety.